# Confusion between .equals and == operator

Tags: java

I know that .equals compares the equality of an object in terms of its value while 
'==' checks the equality in terms of the reference and the value.

This code:

String s1="hi";
String s2=new String("hi");
Here both s1 and s2 have same hashcode, so even s1==s2 should return true but its giving false.
I need a clear understanding on this.

Comment: change `in terms of the reference and the value.` to `in terms of the reference`

Comment: "s1 and s2 have the same hashcode" - so what?

Comment: So doesn't it means they have same memory reference and it should return true then?